# Why don't regular expression engines support all set operations?

Tags: regex, state-machine, regular-language, finite-automata

Similar to this question on a private forum: [Why don’t RegEx implementations support intersection and complement?](https://forum.snap.berkeley.edu/t/why-dont-regex-implementations-support-intersection-and-complement/5672)

Finite automatas built from regular expressions are closed under the set operations union, intersection, complement, and difference. These FA are closed under the two additional operations concatenation and Kleene star.

Anecdotally, concatenation, union, and star operations are ubiquitous in regular expression implementations. Why don't regular expression engines typically support the other set operations intersection, complement, and difference?

An example FA demonstrating the intersection of the two FA `substring 01` and `odd number of 1s` from [these lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec03.pdf).

[image: FA construction showing closure under intersection]
Citation:

> Scott Aaronson. 6.045J Automata, Computability, and Complexity. Spring 2011. Massachusetts Institute of Technology: MIT OpenCourseWare, https://ocw.mit.edu. License: Creative Commons BY-NC-SA.

Comment: Thanks so much @Aaron. I haven't tried to implement lookaround yet so didn't realize how the algorithm worked. Do you know any use case for difference op?

Comment: Makes plenty of sense, thanks for leaving helpful comments @Aaron. If you have free time and want to convert your comments to an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: Turns out the guess was wrong, regular expressions did originate from an academic background. In foresight that should have been the default guess given the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex engines that support lookarounds let you implement intersection, complement and difference :

- `(?=pattern1)pattern2` will match a string that both pattern1 and pattern2 match
- `(?!pattern).*` will match anything that isn't matched by pattern (although more realistically you'd use `pattern` as a regex and have your higher-level environment reverse the match result)
- `(?!pattern1)pattern2` will match a string that is matched by pattern2 but not by pattern1

However lookarounds are a rather recent feature in the history of regular expressions and still aren't supported by many regex engines. Why is that?
I'm not well versed in regex's history, but if I believe a cursory glance at Wikipedia articles, they originate from mathematician Stephen Cole Kleene's [definition of regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Formal_definition) which is only based on the union, concatenation and Kleene star operations, which might explain why those are the basic operations in regular expressions.